# How to install one package on multiple nodes using Spacewalk?

Tags: scientific-linux, spacewalk

Currently, when one package would like to be installed on multiple nodes using Spacewalk, a system is selected in the System Overview, an install installable package is searched in the software menu, selected and subsequently installed.

These steps have to be repeated for every node. How to select multiple Systems and subsequently install one package using Spacewalk instead installing it per system individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality is called "system set manager" for dynamic groups and "system groups" for pre-defined groupings. See this [screenshot](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/img/screenshots/system-set-manager.png) and the getting started guide from the [Red Hat Satellite manuals](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Satellite/) 
 `–  HBruijn 3 hours ago`

As requested copied as an answer, but a two line comment with two links does not make a good one :(

Especially since your question is about core functionality in your tooling.  I strongly recommend every professional to read (or at least glance through) the manuals to have a rough understanding of the capabilities and features of their tooling. As you discovered even simple and obvious things can greatly improve your productivity and effectivity.

Comment: for screenshots of System Set Manager the link does not work, try https://spacewalkproject.github.io/screenshots.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a node(server) group and add any server to it that you deem necessary.

In the Spacewalk WebUI go to Systems, then click into your group, then click the button at top right that says "work with group"

Select the package tab and choose either some or all of the package's that apply and then click apply package.